# How to echo variables in the middle of messages provided from translation array?

Tags: php

So I'm making a CMS from scratch, a CMS that will support multiple languages.

I have separate .php translation file for each supported language. I `require_once` the right translation file according to the user setting. If they choose to view site in English then they get `require_once 'lang/english.php';`, etc. This is the content of english.php:

```
<?php
function text($phrase){
    static $text = array(
        'WELCOME'                           => 'Welcome to the CrappyCMS!',
        'NEW_MEMBER'                        => 'This user is new. What a scrub.',
        'ERROR_EMPTY_FIELDS'                => 'Please fill in all of the required fields.'
    );
    return $text[$phrase];
}
```

For example, I basically use `echo text('WELCOME');` in my home page to display the welcome message in right language.

Now I have some old code from my earlier CMS that has this kind of error recording in the user registration page:

```
if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true){
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username \'' . $_POST['username'] . '\' is already taken.';
}
if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) == true){
    $errors[] = 'Username must not contain any spaces.';
}
if (email_exists($_POST['email']) === true){
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, the email \'' . $_POST['email'] . '\' is already in use.';
}
```

(I know it's probably vulnerable code but I'll fix it later, don't mind security)

I want to edit it to return array keys to refer to translation array's values, such as this:

```
if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true){
    $errors[] = 'ERROR_USERNAME_TAKEN';
}
```

Then I will have an array entry in my translation file for 'ERROR_USERNAME_TAKEN' through which I will display the error(s).

Now finally to the question, I'm not sure how I can display things like user-entered username in the middle of the message and do it in elegant and simple way. As you can see my old CMS shows `$_POST['username']` in the middle of the error message. I'm not sure how I can implement this in efficient way to my new CMS.

I would show you my solution but sadly I don't have one in mind, things that come into my mind currently are kinda absurd, inefficient and very dirty.

Any input is welcome.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, gettext and similar systems are proven and stable and already have an answer for your questions. Which usually boils down to `printf`: `Sorry, the username '%s' is already taken.`

Comment: I saw some dude doing it like this:
`"ERROR_USERNAME_TAKEN" => array("Sorry, the username ","is already taken.")`. So you would use the split parts of the array or something.

Comment: @Phiter That's pretty useless when your target languages use a completely different word order, and there's no indication where the placeholders are...

Comment: Yeah I know. That's not a good option but maybe OP could work around with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php provides the functionality for this.

```
$welcome = 'Welcome to the %s!';
$cms = 'CrappyCMS';
echo sprintf($welcome, $cms);
// echoes: Welcome to the CrappyCMS!
```

Else you could write your own preg_replace function.